# .NET DateTime to String

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a easy way to convert a DateTime object to a string representation like this
'2010-03-03 10:38:48'.

I'm not sure what the above format is but it is different from the patterns obtainable via ToLongTimeString() etc.

Is this a case for string builder?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this:

```
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
```

If you want 24 hour time, replace `hh` with `HH`.

For more information, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Comment: I think you want lower case "mm" for the minutes.

Comment: Thanks, worked fine with uppercase btw will change for aesthetic reasons though.

Comment: @Chin: It did not work fine with uppercase.  An uppercase `MM` will give months, not minutes.

Comment: @SLaks - Yes you are right. Looked good the first time I looked at it.