# DateTime User Claim, format date as string (Asp.Net MVC 5)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Trying to add a Claim of type DateOfBirth to my userIdentity in my IdentityModels file.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateofBirth { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth, this.DateofBirth));


        return userIdentity;
    }


}
```

2 errors of Code CS1503:

> Argument1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IO.BinaryReader'
>   Argument2: cannon convert from 'System.DateTime' to
>   'System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity'

So obviously I have type errors but I just don't know how to convert my DateTime to a string.

Thanks

Comment: `DateOfBirth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are serveral standard ways to format datetimes as strings in .NET.

1. Use a pre-specified format (i.e. `DateOfBirth.ToString("s")` for a sortable format (source: [.net docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings))
2. Specify a custom format (i.e. `DateOfBirth.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")` (source: [.NET DateTime to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368253/net-datetime-to-string)). You can take out pieces and change delimiters/surrounding text as expected, but there are also format specifiers for shortened formats an smaller time units.

For future reference, a better title to this question may be "C#: How to convert datetime to string" or another title that conveys that part that has you stuck. Then you'll get more views from people who understand your issue.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

by the definition of the method, its saying needs to add as a string